# How to validate a string contains certain characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to check if a string contains certain characters. I was going to use regex, but my string may not have a format.

I would like to ensure that i'm allowing only the following characters

```
1. + symbol
2. - symbol
3. numbers 0~9
4. (
5. )
6. . (dot)
7. spaces
```

Comment: What do you mean, your "string may not have a format"?  What are you validating exactly?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean when you say "may not have a format"?

Comment: Possibly "but I can't work out what to put in the regex to make it work"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This regex will match a string containing only those characters:

```
^[+\-0-9(). ]+$
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/dchAw/)

Comment: Would help if you showed how to use the regex without visiting your demo, thus: 
```if (value.match(/^[+\-0-9(). ]+$/g)) {
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

```
if ( string.match('[^(). +\-0-9]') ) {
    alert("Invalid string");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  var isValid = /^[\x2B\x2D\x28\x29\x2E\s\d]+$/.test(input); 
  if(isValid ) {
      //...

  } else { 
    //..invalid
  }
```